# Structure of an HTTP Header?

Tags: http, headers

Is there an RFC I can look at for the structure of an HTTP header?

I've looked here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

but this seems specific to Headers defined in the spec. I'd like something more generic that might be applied to anyone creating a custom header.

Thanks.

Comment: If you modify the header than it won't be considered an http packet...

Comment: Aren't there custom headers defined by CDN's? such as the ones that come back like "x-CDN" or whatever? Those aren't in the spec. And I'm not asking to MODIFY a header that I've received. I'm asking about creating my own header.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
   message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
   field-name     = token
   field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
   field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
                    and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
                    of token, separators, and quoted-string>
```

source:

```
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers are simple `NAME: VALUE` pairs, written one per line and separated by a carriage-return and a line-feed (`¶`). The last line of the headers must be blank. Custom headers will be ignored by clients/servers that don't understand them, and should be of the form `x-Custom-Name: Value`

For example:

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1¶
 Host: superuser.com¶
 Connection: close¶
 x-My-Custom-Header: Foo; bar=baz¶
 Accept: text/html,*/*;q=0.8¶
 ¶
```

Further reading can be found in [RFC 7230#4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2), [RFC 2616#4.2 (deprecated)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2) and [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822)